# Shiny: convert character string into numeric vector within eventReactive

Tags: r, shiny

I have just started experimenting with Shiny. What I am trying to do seem very easy, but I cannot get it right.

I only would like to get two strings of values separated by commas, and then, when the action button “go” is pressed, convert those strings to numeric vectors, and plotting one against the other.

The problem seems to be the conversion of the character strings to the numeric vectors.  In R, i generally use the following line and works OK

```
x<-"2,4,6,98"
y<-as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x,",")))
y
[1]  2  4  6 98
```

but when the same is included within “eventReactive” I get

> Error in as.double: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'

Here is the code I tried:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Plot data"),
  sidebarPanel(
    textInput(inputId = "Conc",label="measured concentrations",value="",
          placeholder ="Enter a numeric vector, comma separated"),
    textInput(inputId = "Time",label="Time", value="",
          placeholder ="Enter a numeric vector, comma separated"),
actionButton("go","Go!")
  ),

  mainPanel(
    plotOutput(outputId = "plot1")
  )
)


server<-function(input, output){

  t<-eventReactive(input$go,{as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(input$Time,",")))})
  parent<-eventReactive(input$go,{as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(input$Conc,",")))})
  pp<-reactive({plot(t,parent)})
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({pp()})
}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't understand what you want, but try this one:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Plot data"),
  sidebarPanel(
    textInput(inputId = "Conc",label="measured concentrations",value="",
              placeholder ="Enter a numeric vector, comma separated"),
    textInput(inputId = "Time",label="Time", value="",
              placeholder ="Enter a numeric vector, comma separated"),
    actionButton("go","Go!")
  ),

  mainPanel(
    plotOutput(outputId = "plot1")
  )
)


server<-function(input, output){
  val<-reactiveValues()

  observeEvent(input$go,{
    val$t<-as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(input$Time,",")))
    val$parent<-as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(input$Conc,",")))

  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    validate(need(val$t,""))
    validate(need(val$parent,""))
    plot(val$t,val$parent)
  })

}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!